# Java EE installation and configuration on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jakarta-ee

I am a newbie for Mac OS. I would like to develop Java EE on Mac OS. Where can i find the development environment configuration such as how to install Java EE, the file structure of Java EE, where is the Java EE file, classpath.

I have searched for some keywords, but most of them are about Tomcat and JBoss configuration.

Could anyone provide link or keyword of Java EE development environment configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, working with servers like JBoss is basically what Java EE is! If you just want plain old Java, that's Java SE and comes with OSX.

The following link from Apple seems like some official advice, but as you noticed it's mostly talking about JBoss and Jetty.

http://developer.apple.com/internet/java/enterprisejava.html

Comment: Thx for ur reply!
So jboss installation will contain all j2ee development enviroment? by the way, the sun provide J2EE installation for mac os, so which one is better?

Comment: I don't think there is a "better". JBoss installation will contain JBoss... is that what you need? Install the tools you need to do the job (or learning) that you're trying to accomplish.